# PhoneStateListener for call receiver not working in real device

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, telephonymanager, phone-state-listener

I've created `BroadCastReceiver` which listens for `IncomingCall` and `Outgoing Calls`. Tried to add `PhoneStateListener` with `TelephonyManager` in  `BroadCastReceiver` which works perfectly on Emulator and some devices.

*It's not working with `Samsung ST 7652`. Always return `CALL_STATE_IDLE` and incoming number `null` .Why is it so?*

As below :

```
public class ReceiverInComingCall extends BroadcastReceiver { 
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    TelephonyManager phone = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    MyPhoneStateListener PhoneListener = new MyPhoneStateListener();
    phone.listen(PhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
   }

  private class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener{
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);

        switch(state){
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
         Log.i("CALL","CALL_STATE_RINGING");
        break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
         Log.i("CALL","CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK");
        break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
         Log.i("CALL","CALL_STATE_IDLE");
        break;
        }
      }
   }
 }
```

***Bugging me out :-***

```
  E/MSimTelephonyManager(621): MSimTelephonyManager sRegistryMsim != null
```

*Why does it giving something like these in `LogCat` when i debugged for `Samsung ST 7652` else it show me perfect Log of Call State?*

***Tried***

[PhoneStateListener not working with some devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20930684/phonestatelistener-not-working-on-samsung-gt-s7562). But it didn't help me with that solution either Always giving me `CALL_STATE_IDLE` and incoming number `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After browsing several source regarding `PhoneStateListeners` and `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE` found what I was looking for and works like a charm regardless of model specific barriers.

***BroadCastReceiver***

```
 public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String str = intent.getAction();
    if ("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE".equals(str))
        inComing(context, intent);

    if ("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL".equals(str))
        outGoing(context, intent);
  }

 private void inComing(Context context, Intent intent){
    String callState = intent.getStringExtra("state");
    if ("RINGING".equals(callState)){
        Log.i(TAG, "RINGING SENDS BUSY");
    }else if ("OFFHOOK".equals(callState)){
        Log.i(TAG, "OFFHOOK SENDS BUSY");
    }else if("IDLE".equals(callState)){
        Log.i(TAG, "IDLE SENDS AVAILABLE"); 
    }
  }

 private void trueCallerOutgoing(Context context, Intent intent)
  {
    String callState = intent.getStringExtra("state");
    if ("RINGING".equals(callState)){
            Log.i(TAG, "RINGING SENDS BUSY");
    }else if ("OFFHOOK".equals(callState)){
            Log.i(TAG, "OFFHOOK SENDS BUSY");
    }else if("IDLE".equals(callState)){
            Log.i(TAG, "IDLE SENDS AVAILABLE"); 
    }
  }
}
```

***Manifest***

```
 <receiver android:name="PhoneStateReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

*With Permission*

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: this is not working. only idle and off hook were called. And no listener when the call is actually accepted.