# Flashlight app doesn't always stop when receiving calls

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make the flashlight turn off whenever a call or SMS message is received.
It works perfectly but in some devices (i.e. HUAWEI devices)
my flash light doesn't turn off when I reject the incoming call.

Relevant code:

```
 else{
        if(phoneManager.getCallState() == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
            if(prefs.getBoolean("call", true)) {
                Log.e("call", "start ->  type:" + prefs.getString("type", ""));
                String tp = prefs.getString("flash_type", "");
                if(!tp.equals(""))
                    flash.startCallFlashLight(getIndex(tp));

                else
                    flash.startCallFlashLight(1);

                lastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
            }
        }

        else if(lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING &&
                ( phoneManager.getCallState() == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK ||
                        phoneManager.getCallState() == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE)) {
            Log.e("call", "stop");
            flash.stopCallFlashLight();
            lastState = -1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: if the code is working in most part of devices, please post stacktrace you have in the problematic ones

Comment: my logcat dont show anything

Comment: mmm... you mean anything strange, because android stacktrace is quite vervosing `xD`, you tried connecting problematic devices to the developing computer?? are the states updated correctly?

Comment: what is android stacktrace? is it part of my IDM to show my problem? Or you mean to debug this part of code?

Comment: which ide are you using? Eclipse? AndroidStudio? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841232/java-android-how-to-print-out-a-full-stack-trace

Comment: android studio i ues

Comment: you KNOW , it doesn't go to this part of my code to apply , so I couldn't get my error to show.else if(lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING &&
                ( phoneManager.getCallState() == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK ||
                        phoneManager.getCallState() == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE))

Comment: well, this if not an error seems an unexpected behaviour, searching a bit, I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22088691/3850595) what says: *PhoneStateListener can not work on many device especially on HUAWEI and ZTE.* and provide a workaround... let me know if you succeed ;)